# cmake using corrext c++ standard when checking for header files

Tags: cmake, compiler-options

I'm building a project using cmake which uses Google's dense hash maps. I need to check that the corresponding header file is present. I therefore added

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
INCLUDE (CheckIncludeFileCXX)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX("sparsehash/dense_hash_map" HAVE_SPARSEHASH)
```

to my `CMakeLists.txt`. However, it fails to find the header when I compile
on some old compiler. The problem is that the header must be compiled in
C++11 and these compiler are not C++11 by default:

```
/usr/bin/clang++      -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4186d.dir/CheckIncludeFile.cxx.o -c /home/florent/src/IVMPG/HPCombi/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.cxx
In file included from /home/florent/src/IVMPG/HPCombi/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.cxx:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/sparsehash/dense_hash_map:102:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/type_traits:35:

/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#error This file requires compiler and library support \
^
```

As a consequence CMake think the file is not present.

So the question is: How do I ensure that I'm using `c++11` (or even `c++14`)
when I'm testing some include or symbols ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX` internally uses [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/try_compile.html), which preserves compiler flags in *CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS* variable, but, until CMake 3.8, it [didn't preserve](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16456) *language standards* (like *CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD* variable).

So, if you have CMake version 3.7 or lower, the only way to ensure checks to use c++11, is to add standard-related option to *CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS* variable before call to `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX`:

```
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
...
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX("sparsehash/dense_hash_map" HAVE_SPARSEHASH)
```

Yes, cross-platform aspects of *CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD* are broken in that case.

If you have CMake version 3.8 or higher, *default* behavior of CMake is still to ignore language standards. This is done for compatibility with older versions. For preserving language standards, set policy [CMP0067](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/policy/CMP0067.html) to *NEW*:

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0067 NEW)
...
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX("sparsehash/dense_hash_map" HAVE_SPARSEHASH)
```

Comment: I got stuck for pretty long on this one on check_cxx_source_compiles - it turns out that you have to specify the policy before you `include(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)`. Changing the policy after has no effect.